# Database update silently fails

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am unable to understand that why this method is not updating database while neither an error nor exception is getting thrown.

```
public void updatelocation(String newloc, String cservice, String cno) {
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase sdb = getWritableDatabase();
        String where = Table_info.Courier_service+ " LIKE ? AND "+Table_info.Courier_no +" LIKE ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{"BLUE DART","BD01"};
        System.out.println(whereArgs);
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(Table_info.Location, newloc);
        sdb.update(Table_info.Table_Name, cv, where, whereArgs);
        Log.v("server Data", "Updation Successful");
        sdb.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("update method error:"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't say the programming language. I thought it could be Java and tagged as such; please correct it if I'm wrong.

Comment: sorry i forgot that but it is in Android....thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your method seems to be fine. Can you print the number of rows affected and see what number it says.

```
sdb.update(Table_info.Table_Name, cv, where, whereArgs);
```

this method will return number of rows affected. If it says '0' then there is something wrong with your where condition.